# How can i limit disk space usage for one user?

Tags: server, disk-usage

Like..
User john123, you can only use 100mb of my harddisk.
User jake155, you can only use 250mb of my harddisk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To restrict hard disk usage per user efficiently we could create a separate partition for each of the `/home` directories. However then it's obviously not so easy to change the granted space or add new users.

We therefore may use fixed sized images as a container for the users `/home` and mount these as loop devices (as root):

```
1 mkdir /media/users/
2 dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/users/john123.img bs=512K count=200
3 mkfs.ext4 /media/users/john123.img
4 mkdir /home/john123
```

For testing:

```
5 mount -o loop /media/users/john123.img /home/john123
```

After having done so we then create our user john123 who will now have 100 MB space available in his `/home/john123`.

Subsequently the loop devices will have to be mounted prior to login, e.g. by adding this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
6 /media/users/john123.img    /home/john123    ext4    loop    0    2
```

Answer (score 9):

The standard way to do it in UNIX is through the `quota` command. It allows you to dynamically change how much disk space each user can use.

See the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/quota.1.html), or google for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The route to take may be to limit the size of a user's home directory, i.e. limit /home/jake155 to a certain size.  Typically a non-admin user cannot access anything beyond their home directory unless you change permissions otherwise.  [This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=935046) discusses multiple ways to do that.